# SQL data convert column to row values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with only one column about 100 rows of only names. But I need to display the 3 names in a row. So that I will get 34 rows each row with 3 names.

Example:

```
Name
_____

Raj
Sam
Guru
Tej
Avin
Sami
Fanst
```

I need to display above data as

```
Name Name1 Name2
____ _____ ______
Raj  Sam    Guru
Tej  Avin   Sami
Fanst
```

No condition just need to covert single column value into 3 columns data.

Oracle DB

Comment: What database are you using?  Each database has a slightly different SQL syntax so each will handle pivoting a little differently

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using conditional aggregation and rownum.  Something like this:

```
select max(case when mod(rn, 3) = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when mod(rn, 3) = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when mod(rn, 3) = 0 then name end) as name3       
from (select name, rownum as rn
      from table t
     ) t
group by trunc((rn - 1) / 3);
```

Comment: I have tried way Gordon said but cannot split into 3 colums as I specified. Let me try wat Gordon said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `CASE`, make a try on it using `PIVOT`

Try to `PIVOT` Your `Name` column like this

```
SELECT Name,Name1,Name2
FROM
(SELECT Name FROM table_name) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
FOR Name IN (Name,Name1,Name2)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `PIVOT` in this situation as you would not know the values to specify in advance.